# which function would be equivalent in R to bysort variable1: generate variable2=_n (stata)

Tags: stata

I have a database with id and hospital visits. The same id can have several visits. I would like to know among those who have more than one visit, what number of visit is equivalent to each hospital admission. In stata I would do:
`bysort id: generate number_visit=_n`

Comment: Better to show with an example in Stata what that code does and then post a data example in R. Questions like this can't be answered unless people are fluent in bith Stata and R, whereas just explaining what you want to do in R would find many more people who know. (No hostility to Stata on my part: it is just that this is not a good kind of question. Also, I am quite experienced in Stata but not in R.)